# Is there a way to export sqlite query result into a csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have bunch of csv files (not a database file) with data in them. Lets assume there are two csv files - Candidate.csv and application.csv

Given email of a candidate, I need to extract relevant information from those two csv and extract them into separate csv files.

Logic -
Given = email of candidate

Run query on candidate.csv - Select * from candidates where Email='blah@example.com'

Dump the results into Candidate-filtered.csv

Using a column "Id" of the candidate record retrieved, run a query on application.csv

Select * from application where candidateId='id retrived from previous query result'

dump the result into application-filtered.csv

I need help with dumping results into those filtered csv (including column header of original csv, so anyone looking at filtered csv, knows which column refers to what data)

I figured I can use SQLITE for loading csv files into in memory tables and running query onto them (and even export the result into a separate csv files. Now SQLITE has a neat way of doing it:

```
.mode csv 
.import 'Candidate.csv candidates'
.headers on
.output 'Candidate-filtered.csv'
Select * from candidates where Email='blah@example.com'
```

However, I want to use Python to do this, because I will have to store variables from each result (like Id of candidates retrieved) and use them in next query (query for application).

For now, I want to try out the code that will work on Candidates.csv.

This is the Python code I have:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

def extract_Candidate():

    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    data = pandas.read_csv('Candidate.csv') 
    data.to_sql('candidates',conn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("Select * from candidates where Email='blah@example.com'")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

candidateRows = extract_Candidate()
print(candidateRows)
```

I don't really need to return candidateRows variable. As long as I can dump the results in csv, it's fine. I can print the retrieved rows in terminal. I don't know how can I dump it in a new csv file (I need all the column headers that were present in original csv file).

Most search engine results show how to export an in memory database into disk. I don't want .db files. I just want to export the results of the query in a csv file. I saw some csv export code, but they are hardcoding column headers. I want it to take whatever column headers are in original csv, without me hardcoding anything.

Next step is to get the column "Id" from all the retreived canddiates, and return them in some sort of array or set. I know it's basic Python, but I know nothing about python (or sqlite for that matter).

Feel free to critique the code as well (I still worry if pandas.read_csv can handle HUGE csv files or not; let me know your thoughts).

Comment: Just to clarify, the only reason you're using sql is for querying the files? Not connecting to a database anywhere? Or are you going to be using the data to update a sql table?

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, only reason i am using SQL is because it makes it easier to search data in a large csv file. I am open to taking any alternative approach to this. I am not updating any existing csv files. 

We basically have archive of large amount of data. And the ask is to extract data specific to a contact, upon demand. So i am writing a script, where email of contact will be input, and script should run through all the csv files and extract data specific to that candidate, and export it all to different csv files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of adding sql complexity, would you accept a solution that works in pure pandas? Regarding your question on pandas size restrictions, generally the only limit is your available system memory which would also be the limit with the SQL solution.

Note that the following solution is untested and theoretical, since we don't have any sample data to test against.

```
import pandas as pd

#we bring in the data
candidates_df = pd.read_csv('Candidate.csv') 
app_df = pd.read_csv('Applications.csv')

#we set the search email
candidate_email = 'blah@example.com'

#we use pandas boolean masking to filter the dataframe and get just the 'id' column
filtered_ids = candidates_df[candidates_df['email']==candidate_email]['id']

#we use the pandas series of ids to filter the applications
filtered_apps = app_df[app_df['id'].isin(filtered_ids)]

#we dump the filtered apps df to a new csv file
filtered_apps.to_csv('directory/file_out.csv')
```

Comment: This is fantastic and it worked. Yeah i can let go of SQL. Now if we have HUGE csv files, is there a way to manage memory? I know pandas allows to specify chunk size. I need to look into it. But if you know at the top of your head, if it would be helpful or not, let me know. Will it automatically handle the line "filtered_ids .... " on each chunk or do i have to manually handle that in code?

Comment: Unfortunately it's gonna be very dependent on your exact specifications, but there are lots of [SO questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/opening-a-20gb-file-for-analysis-with-pandas) and [articles](https://medium.com/@vincentteyssier/filtering-csv-files-bigger-than-memory-to-a-pandas-dataframe-3ab51ff993fd) that can help if you need to do that. But yes, there will need to be some sort of code solution. If you get stuck, you can always ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a ton @G. Anderson.